# How to make these Buttons function when pressed with a key?

Tags: java, jbutton, keyevent

1. This is the code.
2. The button doesnt work with key, if i dont click it first. It would
   be great if you could help me.

I used eclipse when i created this frame

This is just an example code, but I just want to know how it functions

For any more detalis, ask here.

```
    import java.awt.EventQueue;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JButton;

    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;


    public class ExampleApp {

    private JFrame frmHi;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton btnAnother;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ExampleApp window = new ExampleApp();
                    window.frmHi.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ExampleApp() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmHi = new JFrame();
        frmHi.setTitle("Hi");
        frmHi.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmHi.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmHi.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Enter");
        btnEnter.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    textField.setText("You pressed enter");
                }
            }
        });
        btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText("Hi there from button");
            }
        });
        btnEnter.setBounds(119, 63, 89, 23);
        frmHi.getContentPane().add(btnEnter);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setEnabled(false);
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setBounds(108, 30, 173, 20);
        frmHi.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        btnAnother = new JButton("Backspace");
        btnAnother.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE){
                    textField.setText("you pressed backspace");
                }
            }
        });
        btnAnother.setBounds(119, 119, 89, 23);
        frmHi.getContentPane().add(btnAnother);
    }

}
```

Comment: which is the question?

Comment: When I press enter it shows nothing even though I wrote the keylistener method, it only works after I click on the button, so the question is how to fix that?

Comment: backspace is working?

Answer (score 1):

Your KeyListener addded to JButton so it works only when the button has focus (after click).

It's better to define [KeyBindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for the keys you have to process.